# What is the fastest way to get multiple data-attributes from the same element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a use case which requires getting multiple html5 data-attributes from elements.  This occurs within a loop across many elements and pushes the data in to an array for caching.

From doing some research it appears that using `el.getAttribute('data-whatever')` is faster than using the native html5 `dataset` method however I need to get around 5 separate data attributes from the same element.

The `dataset` method allows you to retrieve all data-attributes with one call and then access them with standard object dot notation ( dataset.index, dataset.whatever, dataset.somethingelse ) whereas using `getAttribute` I have to make repeated getAttribute calls to retrieve all the needed data.

If using non compliant attributes I can of course simply use dot notation to access the properties speeding up this function considerably.  But using html5 data attributes this does not work (i.e. el.data-whatever will always be undefined).

I wish to remain compliant to standards therefore I am looking for the fastest possible way of retrieving these multiple data attributes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make tests at http://jsperf.com

Comment: It seems unlikely that fetching attributes from DOM nodes would be the focal point of performance.  Have you profiled your code with Firefox or Chrome (or anything else) to look for "hot spots"?

Comment: @Pointy Yes I have profiled in detail.  This is an extremely unusual use case and as such this kind of optimization is actual warranted.  Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just benchmark it :

http://jsperf.com/dataset-access-vs-getattrb

It still looks to be 2 times faster using `getAttribute` on chrome.

I'm using a `noop` to prevent the JIT from optimizing it away.

Comment: The funny thing is that if you only request: `el.dataset` it is multiply times faster than getting all the attributes - in chrome.

Comment: as said on your bench, it has no side-effects and is just optimized away. Try with a function call.

Comment: @user1737909 Okay i'm confused.  NULL's answer is very clear, yet your results seem to differ.  If you could explain in your answer why your results are correct I will gladly award you the answer.  Cheers :)

Comment: I said it in the last line : 1) I'm not using an object to store it 2) I'm using a `noop` function to avoid the JIT optimizing the access away (because it has no side effect).

Comment: Also, I'm comparing accessing 5 attributes vs accessing 5 attributes

Comment: Okay, it is clear that your knowledge of compilers far exceeds mine so I will have to take your word for it.  Many thanks for the answer and solution.

Answer (score 5):

I made this test:

http://jsperf.com/dataset-vs-getattribute-2

The test is a the following:

**dataset all:**

```
var data = el.dataset;
```

**getAttribute all:**

```
var data = {
    id: el.getAttribute('data-id'),
    user: el.getAttribute('data-user'),
    dateOfBirth: el.getAttribute('data-date-of-birth')
};
```

**dataset single:**

```
var user = el.dataset.user;
```

**getAttribute single:**

```
var user = el.getAttribute('user');
```

[image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.dataset

Comment: I think the first example is optimized by the JIT because it has no side effects.

Comment: also, your `getAttribute all` creates an object. no very fair